# How to compile a h2o mojo in order to score a csv file

Tags: h2o

To whom may it concern,

With pojo, I was able to write two line java codes to score a csv file.

However, with mojo, I am not sure how to do the same. I was searching but could not find a suitable example.

Can you kindly guide me how to do it?

Many thanks in advance,
Kere

Comment: This question might get more usefuls answers if you show the two lines of java (and anything else that is involved) that you use for POJO.

Answer (score 0):

The MOJO documentation is in the [same location](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html) as the POJO docs in the Javadoc.  It is also easily findable in the [H2O User Guide](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/pojo-quick-start.html) by searching the term "MOJO". Here is a direct link to the [MOJO Quickstart Guide](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/overview-summary.html#quickstartmojo).